# 3.1 Upgrade and Extension Updates via Composer error

Tags: silverstripe

I am upgrading an existing SS install from 3.0.4 to 3.1. I followed the instructions here for upgrading: http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/installation/upgrading

Now I am attempting to update a couple SS modules via Composer (specifically I have tried to update Comments and DataObjectsAsPage). I have updated the composer.json file in my root to the following:

```
{
"name": "silverstripe/installer",
"description": "The SilverStripe Framework Installer",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.2",
    "silverstripe/cms": "3.1.x-dev",
    "silverstripe/framework": "3.1.x-dev",
    "silverstripe-themes/simple": "*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "silverstripe/docsviewer": "*",
    "silverstripe/behat-extension": "*",
    "silverstripe/buildtools": "*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
},
"config": {
    "process-timeout": 600  
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"silverstripe/comments": "*",
"arambalakjian/dataobjectaspage": "*"
```

}

I then navigate to my project directory and run both of the following

```
composer update silverstripe/comments
composer update arambalakjian/dataobjectaspage
```

When attempting to update both extensions, I have received the same error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Problem 1
- Installation request for silverstripe/cms 3.1.x-dev -> satisfiable by silverstripe/cms[3.1.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: silverstripe/cms[3.1.x-dev, 3.0.3].
- Installation request for silverstripe/cms == 3.0.3.0 -> satisfiable by silverstripe/cms[3.0.3].
```

How do I update extensions via Composer?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
composer require silverstripe/comments
composer require arambalakjian/dataobjectaspage
```

Which should define your project's requirements.
Check out http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/installation/composer which has a quite extensible details on how to use composer with SS

Comment: I have tried using the require command and am still receiving the same error.

Comment: I realized the cause of the error above was having the composer.lock file left over from the 3.0.3 install. Once I deleted the composer.lock file, I no longer received the error above. I will submit as answer shortly.

Comment: After adding the silverstripe/comments to the require section of my composer.json file and running composer update silverstripe/comments I now get an error: `Can only install one of: silverstripe/cms[3.1.x-dev, 3.1.0-beta3].` Maybe this is due to the installer composer.json file?

Comment: Removing the existing vendor directory and running `composer update` removed all errors and I was able to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Colymba's answer was correct, but I did want to elaborate in case anyone else comes across these errors...

I did the following to install the modules via Composer:

First, I removed the composer.lock file that remained from the 3.0.4 install. Next, I deleted my vendor directory and ran

```
composer update
```

This updated my Silverstripe install to 3.1 ( note if you have customized the 'simple' theme and do not want it overwritten you would want to either remove it from the required section of your composer.json file or rename it ) and I was able to then run

```
composer require silverstripe/comments
```

The most up to date version of the module was installed successfully.